# Dobule Word with Hyphen(-) Htaccess Redirection Not works in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently I have created a .htaccess redirection to my dynamic site. 
In the redirection single-word url works perfectly. example: `http://example.com/pincode/assam.php` (no issue)
At the same time this link not works `http://example.com/pincode/andhra-pradesh.php` (issue)

I have stored state name andhra pradesh as "`Andhra Pradesh`" in my db and i have used "`strtolower`" and "`str_replace`(' ', '-')" functions to get the result as "andhra-pradesh.php" in my php file.

Here it is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /pincode/(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^pincode/(.*).php$ pinstate.php?st=$1 [L]
```

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: It should be working. What is the issue? Do you get a 404? Also, no need for the `RewriteCond`, as the same thing is being checked for in the rule itself.

Comment: What exactly is not working?